# Excel VBA adding Values field in Pivot Table not working

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to add a Values field in my Pivot table. Here is the code I have for now :

```
 'Insert Row Fields
   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Account Lvl1 Desc")
   .Orientation = xlRowField
   .Position = 1
   End With
   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Account Description")
   .Orientation = xlRowField
   .Position = 2
   End With
   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Supplier")
   .Orientation = xlRowField
   .Position = 3
   End With

 'Insert Data Field
   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable")

   .PivotFields ("Distrib Amt CAD")
   .Orientation = xlDataField
   .Function = xlSum
   '.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
   .Name = "Sum of OH in CAD "
   End With
```

Everything else is working but the Values

Comment: What line are you getting the error ?

Comment: I am not getting any error, it is simply not displaying the pivot table with the Values, it's only showing the Row Fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend some clean-up:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable")
   'Insert Row Fields
   With .PivotFields("Account Lvl1 Desc")
       .Orientation = xlRowField
       .Position = 1
   End With
   With .PivotFields("Account Description")
       .Orientation = xlRowField
       .Position = 2
   End With
   With .PivotFields("Supplier")
       .Orientation = xlRowField
       .Position = 3
   End With
   'Insert Data Field 
   With .PivotFields ("Distrib Amt CAD")
       .Orientation = xlDataField
       .Function = xlSum
       '.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
       .Name = "Sum of OH in CAD "
   End With
End With
```

If you have values that you, say, exported from SharePoint field tables, those are strings... run a similar code to the below on your data so you can display as a number:

```
With sws 'source worksheet
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lr
        .Cells(i, 6).Value = Val(.Cells(i, 6).Value) * 1 'Uses column 6 (F)
    Next i
End With
```

Once the appropriate data exists, it will give more than #Value errors on the output.